# Can I get rid of template specialisation with std::enable_if?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I read about `std::enable_if` for:

> function overloading based on arbitrary properties of type

So I was trying to overload class ctors via `enable_if` (like below) but i get error saying that `enable_if` cannot be used to disable declaration and this in both lines when I used `std::enable_if` :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>


template <typename T>
class cls
{
public:

    cls (T a, typename std::enable_if< std::is_same<T, int>::value >::type  * Dummy = 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Ctor for int\n";
    }

    cls (T a, typename std::enable_if< std::is_same<T, char>::value >::type  * Dummy = 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Ctor for char\n";
    }
};

int main()
{

    cls a(10);
    cls b('x');

    return 0;
}
```

So is it possible to overload ctors using `enbale_if`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: @NathanOliver : I want to add 2 members vars say X and Y one will be available for tytpe int and the second for char so I started with ctors . So tthe work is not all finished :)

Comment: It doesn't seem like you need any specialization or SFINAE for that.  You can just overload the constructors, one taking an `int` and one taking a `char`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, e.g. when you instantiate a `cls<int>`, you'll always get a failed requirement from the 2nd constructor overloaing, i.e. `std::enable_if< std::is_same<T, char>::value >::type` with `T` is `int`. And it's same for `cls<char>`.

You can make the constructors templates to make [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) taking effect; which will get rid of template specializations from the overload set and won't cause compile error. e.g.

```
template <typename X = T>
cls (X a, typename std::enable_if< std::is_same<X, int>::value >::type  * Dummy = 0)
{
    std::cout << "Ctor for int\n";
}

template <typename X = T>
cls (X a, typename std::enable_if< std::is_same<X, char>::value >::type  * Dummy = 0)
{
    std::cout << "Ctor for char\n";
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hye3JCgh16F39XFo)

Comment: will not that make automatic type deduction disabled ? I will have to specify the type say `cls<int> a(10);` and `cls<char> b('x');`

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd I think you have to add [user-defined deduction guides](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#User-defined_deduction_guides); see the live demo I posted.

Comment: You could also make it [simpler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4IxPz7XLwe2E3YxL) by making the `enable_if` a template parameter.  Then you only need one deduction guide.

Comment: @MilesBudnek : Ha yes ;)

Comment: @songyuanyao : Yup great, that made my day, I was seeing for deduction guide and here you gave me an example. Thx

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to need `enable_if` here, just a regular constructor:

```
cls(T a) { std::cout << "Ctor for T\n"; }
```

To disable a template class specialization do not provide its definition:

```
template<> class cls<void>; // disabled specialization.
```

Comment: yeah I know that But for test purpose to see the nebale_if work. I even thought about making members vars accessible for one type and not for another.

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd If you want to have different member variables for different types you will need a specialization.  `enable_if` won't help you there.